# Hide params from angular url post request

Tags: angularjs, http, spring-mvc, post

I have this angular scope function, which is responsible to send a POST request.

```
 $scope.addStuff = function(p1, p2) {
        $http.post('stufflist/addStuff/' + p1 + '/' + p2, 
                   {}, 
                   {params: {'value': stuffValue}}
                  ).then(function successCallback(response) {

                   }, function errorCallback(response) {

                   });
                 };
```

And then I have this Mapping (I am using Spring-mvc):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addStuff/{p1}/{p2}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody void addStuff(@PathVariable("p1") String p1, @PathVariable("p2") String p2, @RequestParam(value = "value") String stuffValue) {
        stuffService.addStuff(p1, p2, stuffValue);
    }
```

This works as intended. However, when analyzing POST request url in browser's console, I see:

```
http://localhost:8080/my-project/stufflist/addStuff/p1/p2/file?value=my_giant_string_which_i_want_to_hide_from_this_url
```

**How can I hide this param from POST request url?**

Answer (score 1):

```
$http({
        url: 'stufflist/addStuff/' + p1 + '/' + p2, 
        method: "POST",
        data: {'value': stuffValue}
    })
    .then(function(response) {
            // success
    }, 
    function(response) { // optional
            // failed
    });
```

Do something like this instead of using `$http.post`

Comment: In console you see this or in the URL ??

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem.

```
$http({
            url: 'stufflist/addStuff/' + p1 + '/' + p2, 
            method: 'post',
            data: $.param({value: stuffValue}),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

      }).then(function successCallback(response) {

         }, function errorCallback(response) {

         });
```